# How to manage Azure DevOps group permissions using Rest API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm working on an automation task where I need a group to have a set of permissions on Repos, Pipelines, and releases, etc. I'm looking for a Rest API that can manage the permissions for this group.

For Example:

At Cross repo policies, how do I manage/set the permissions for the group "PROJECT ADMINISTRATORS" to allow the "Bypass policies when pushing", "Bypass policies when pushing", etc using a Rest API.

[image]

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Check out https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/

Comment: You can use fiddler to capture most of the REST API calls.

Comment: Did you look at the REST API documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you could use the Rest API: [Access Control Entries - Set Access Control Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries/set%20access%20control%20entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrolentries/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=6.0
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "token": "repoV2/{ProjectID}/{RepoID(If you want to set the permission for a single repo)}",
  "merge": true,
  "accessControlEntries": [
    {
      "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-....",
      "allow": 32768,
      "deny": 0,
      "extendedinfo": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

You can get the parameter values needed in the Rest API through the following methods：

**securityNamespaceId：**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/_apis/securitynamespaces?api-version=6.0
```

In the Response Body: you could search for the **Git Repositories**.

Then you could get the **namespaceid** and Parameter values corresponding to permissions.

For example:

[image]

To get the **Group Identity(S-...)**, there is no directly Rest API to get it. You use the following method to get it:

1.Get the descriptor:

```
 GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

2.Using the following C# code to convert it:

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
        {
            var lengthMod4 = base64EncodedData.Length % 4;
            if (lengthMod4 != 0)
            {
                //fix Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string
                base64EncodedData += new string('=', 4 - lengthMod4);
            }
            var base64EncodedBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
        }

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
```

Here has [a blog](https://blog.devopsabcs.com/index.php/2019/06/24/one-project-to-rule-them-all-3/) which written by our Azure Identity Team engineer, you could refer to it for more detailed information.

In addition, you can also obtain the values of all parameters directly through the browser F12 record.

[image]